# Writing keys and value to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I currently have made a program that takes words from a webpage counts them, then prints the results out with the word and how many times it shows up

ex)

- the, 4
- hello,10
- am, 12

instead of printing the keys and value I want to be able to write them to a text file. currently this is what it looks like

```
def create_dictionary(clean_word_list):
 word_count = {}
 for word in clean_word_list:
    if word in word_count:
        word_count[word] += 1
    else:
        word_count[word] = 1
 for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print(key, value)
```

as you can see at the end its printing the key and value but how to I write that to a txt file instead?

Comment: Not actually what you're asking, but your code can be way simpler with https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Try `word_count = Counter(clean_word_list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
 def create_dictionary(clean_word_list):
     word_count = {}
     f = open("filename.txt", "w")
     for word in clean_word_list:
         if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1
         else:
            word_count[word] = 1
     for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        print(key, value)
        f.write('{} {}'.format(key, value))
     f.close()
```

Format the output in `f.write` part as you wish.

Comment: `collections.Counter` and `with open(filename,mode) as f:` would make it nicer ;)

Answer (score 2):

For counting the `collections.Counter` specialized dict is the right tool, simply stuff your list in it and it counts it for you. 
If writing to files use the  `with open(filename, "w") as fileHandle:` - approach that autocloses the filehandle when you leave the scope.

Combined:

```
from collections import Counter

text = """ No idea what kind  of text you got. But sometinmes it is usefull to know about 
collections.Counter if you want to count things. Now some repetetive stuff:
Abba BBa Abba BBa Abba Abba Abba BBa BBa Cba"""

# split text into lines at '\n', split the lines into words at ' ' and cleanup whitespace
splitText = [x.strip() for y in text.split('\n') for x in y.split(' ') 
             if len(x.strip()) > 0]

# 1-line count the words: 
c =  Counter(splitText)

# output to file
with open("myfile.txt","w") as f:
    for i in c:
        f.write(f"{i},{str(c[i])}\n") 
        # print(f"{i},{str(c[i])}")  # output to console
```

Counter has convenience functions to output f.e. the top 5 counted words:

```
print(c.most_common(3))  # gimme top 3 counted things as list of tuples (word,count)
```

Output:  `[('Abba', 5), ('BBa', 4), ('you', 2)]`

**Doku:**

- [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Output-File:

```
No,1
idea,1
what,1
kind,1
of,1
text,1
you,2
got.,1
But,1
sometinmes,1
it,1
is,1
usefull,1
to,2
know,1
about,1
collections.Counter,1
if,1
want,1
count,1
things.,1
Now,1
some,1
repetetive,1
stuff:,1
Abba,5
BBa,4
Cba,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just add file output to your existing code by:
1. Opening a file for writing
2. Telling the print function to write to that file

```
def create_dictionary(clean_word_list):
  word_count = {}
  for word in clean_word_list:
    if word in word_count:
      word_count[word] += 1
    else:
      word_count[word] = 1
  with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
      print(key, value, file=output)
```

The `with` statement provides context management of the file object and is considered a best practice. If anything raises an exception within the scope of the `with` statement, the file will automatically be closed. The same is true when you exit the `with` block scope naturally (e.g. you've iterated across all items in the dict).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `json` module. It wouldn't result in the output format that you posted, but it has the benefit of being easily readable back into a dictionary.

For instance:

```
import json
word_count = {
  'the': 4,
  'hello': 10,
  'am': 12
}
open("output.txt", "w").write(json.dumps(word_count))
```

The contents of the file would be:

```
{
  "the": 4, 
  "am": 12, 
  "hello": 10
}
```

But you can read this file back into a dictionary using `json.loads()`:

```
word_counts_dict_from_file = json.loads(open('output.txt', 'r').read())
```